# CSS positive relative positioning (top, left, bottom or right) with negative margin which cancel the summation of the values

Tags: css

I cam across a negative margin with a positive position. For example:

```
.headline {
    top: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The end result looks similar with:

```
.headline {
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

What is the difference of using one over the others?

Comment: The end result would appear to be the same, however without more context it's hard to say because there could be other factors involved that you didn't include.

Comment: if you have `background-images` this is a way to center things

Comment: This question just came across my mind because I am reading a book now and trying to understand the css layout & positioning. So I am confused over the snippet which use negative margin with positive position instead of simply a fix position. I don't have much context in this question because I am not trying to solve any problem.

Comment: Is it convenient for you to share some factors that might cause the two to be different? (i.e. a simple example or some cases where those 2 might result in different outcomes. )

Comment: You only want to use `position:relative; top:10px;` on an inline level element, because the simple margin won't apply. For inline block or block it doesn't matter, but be aware it may affect the position of the content on the next line, you'll have to do some tests.

Comment: @Pangloss I made a mistake in the question, the snippet in the book indeed have `position: relative` thank you for noticing.

Comment: And `position:relative; top:0;` does not do anything. The relative position is relative to the element itself.

Comment: @Pangloss it's just an example, if lets say we change to `top: 10px`, then it would looks the same with `margin-top: -100px; top: 110px;`. Wouldn't it? (As long the summation is equal to the orginal)

Comment: Yes, but watch out the content next to it - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6u53o70/) totally missed positioned.

Comment: Thank you @Pangloss, I've managed to understand the the difference after testing out myself https://jsfiddle.net/j0L87qpq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `margin` the element is really moved.

With `top` the displaying is moved, but the **occupied place is not moved**.

See this example:
http://codepen.io/OPiMedia/pen/NqwRZP

Comment: Thanks for the short brief explanation. :) Now, I understand it after looking at your answer and trying it out at https://jsfiddle.net/j0L87qpq/

Answer (score 0):

With `top`, your element must have *`position` property has a value other than `static`*.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-top

By default, the `position` property is `static`. So by default, `top` property doesn't work.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

Comment: I couldn't understand the document. What does it mean by `Static` position? (it said "The box is a normal box, laid out according to the normal flow. The 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties do not apply.")

Comment: I just updated my question, the snippet is using `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

- Negative margins wont work on inline elements so they have to be
  `display:block` or `display:inline-block`
- Position properties wont work on `position:static` which is the
  default.

Have a look at  **[this](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/rVYMJM)**  example.

Here we have 2 inline-block elements which means the `margin-top:-30px` will work, but the `top:-30px` wont because of the position property being defaulted to static.
If we set the position to relative then the blue block will move up another 30px.

Comment: i just updated my question, i forget to include the `position: relative`